# Detect if Block is active in Concrete5

Tags: php, concrete5

Concrete5 Blocks do not get deleted when they are "removed" because of consistency reasons in the history.

Now I have the following situation:
I have a **custom block** with the database table called *btMyCustomBlock*.

It looks like this:

```
 |---bID---|---cID---|---someParam---|
```

Now, when such a block is "removed" and the Page is saved, the database will still maintain the block - which is ok.

BUT: I need a way to detect if my block is used on this page right now. I am looking for something like:

> Select a random entry from btMyCustomBlock WHERE entry is used as a block on the page right now.

How can I do that? I found out that the table *Blocks* has the field `bIsActive` but it seems that this does not correlate with what I am looking for, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this

```
SELECT b.*
FROM btMyCustomBlock b
INNER JOIN CollectionVersionBlocks cvb ON b.bID = cvb.bID
INNER JOIN CollectionVersions cv ON cvb.cvID = cv.cvID
WHERE cv.cvIsApproved = 1
```

Get all the records that are connected to the currently approved page version.

Comment: I'll try that and then I'll give you feedback :)

Comment: I ended up adding `WHERE ... AND cv.cvID=CURRENT_VERSION` whereas `CURRENT_VERSION` is given by `Page::getCurrentPage()->getVersionId()`. This did work just perfect!